# Why does FourierSinSeries return zero?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I wonder why FourierSinSeries returns 0 in this case:

```
oscrect = UnitStep[Mod[x, 2 Pi] - Pi]
s = FourierSeries[oscrect, x, 11]
% // FullSimplify // Expand
si = FourierSinSeries[oscrect, x, 11]
```

This produces the following output on MMA 11.3:

$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i e^{-i x}}{\pi }+\frac{i e^{i x}}{\pi }-\frac{i e^{-3 i x}}{3 \pi }+\frac{i e^{3 i x}}{3 \pi }-\frac{i e^{-5 i x}}{5 \pi }+\frac{i e^{5 i x}}{5 \pi }$

$-\frac{2 \sin (x)}{\pi }-\frac{2 \sin (3 x)}{3 \pi }-\frac{2 \sin (5 x)}{5 \pi }+\frac{1}{2}$

$0$

Here is a graph:

[image: Square wave and a Fourier series]

Comment: Look at the result of Plot[oscrect, {x, 0, Pi}] and in ? FourierSinSeries.

Comment: OK I see, thanks.

Comment: If you had done a shift so that the function being expanded is odd, you'd have gotten your expected result: `FourierSinSeries[UnitStep[Mod[x, 2 Pi] - Pi] - 1/2, x, 7] + 1/2`